# Need help on query sum total quantity show wrong output

Tags: mysql, sql

Process:

- When user buy item and check out then there's cart and cart items table to store the transaction.
- 1 cart_id have many item which stored in cart items table.
- After purchase succeed, then will generate a purchase order id and stored in purchase order table .
- In purchase order table, id_cart and status will be stored.

From here, i am trying to calculate quantity based on id_product or id branch or etc from the purchase made.
There is receiving and ordered quantity field, which in some cases quantity received field might be null, so i will take ordered quantity value.

This is my query

```
SELECT id_product,sum(DISTINCT(COALESCE(received_qty, quantity)))
 FROM (SELECT C.id_cart,C.received_qty,C.quantity , P.id_product, 
   PO.id_purchase_order, PO.status
   FROM (SELECT * FROM cart_items WHERE id_cart IN (SELECT id_cart FROM purchase_orders)) AS C
   LEFT JOIN products as P on p.id_product = c.id_product
   LEFT JOIN purchase_orders AS PO ON C.id_cart = PO.id_cart ) AS A
 GROUP By A.id_product
```

Table data

[image: Cart Item]
[image: Purchase Order]
 The cart id in will be duplicated based on product's supplier. Because need to track and send separately to supplier.

Result

[image: Result]

By right the product id for 1212 should be 1 and 1223 is 2, total qty =3.

What's wrong with my query ?

Comment: Run your inner query.  Does it only return 3 rows?

Comment: @Eric yes, inner query will return all the cart_items data

Answer (score 1):

Your outer joins seem to cause multiplication of your data, but there are so many unnecessary layers of fluff in your query that I cant make it out exactly.
How about just this:

```
SELECT id_product, sum(COALESCE(received_qty, quantity)) AS Nmbr
FROM cart_items 
GROUP BY id_product
```

If you want to make sure the cart is in your purchase_orders:

```
SELECT c.id_product, sum(COALESCE(c.received_qty, c.quantity)) AS Nmbr
FROM cart_items c
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id_cart FROM purchase_orders) p ON p.id_cart = c.id_cart 
GROUP BY c.id_product
```

Comment: If without joining purchase order table then the result is correct, if joined purchase orders table then the result will be same as mine.

Comment: Then the reason of the unexpected result is that the same cart_id is used in different purchase orders. If a cart with items is sold twice, the quantity doubles, of course.

Comment: Oh, is there any solution to solve this? Because the purchase order need to be separately send to supplier. So there will be duplicate id_cart in purchase order record based on the product's supplier.

Comment: You need a way to identify the supplier for each item.

Comment: Can you guide me or give me some idea how to handle it?

Comment: What does your `products` table look like?

Comment: My products table just store the details of the product such as name, uom, price etc.. no duplicated data.

Comment: Updated second query to avoid multiplication of results.

Comment: Yeah, i already use query similar to yours, but when i join another table again like Catalog table which use to store which product belong to which catalog. Then the duplicated row happen again. If using distinct id_product in catalog table is fine, but when trying to get some field from the table then will caused duplicated row.

Comment: You should post a new question for that. Then you can describe the catalog table in detail.